# How to format the date in different style using angular material if user enter the date using keyboard

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

When user enter the date using keyboard date must appear in DD/MM/YYYY format instead of simple number which currently happening with when user try to enter the date using keyboard

Comment: You need to provide some code to see what you have tried so far and what exactly help you need.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/ can help you to achieve what you are asking for